# URL from string gives null

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a string which gives the path, and another which appends the parameters to it. When i put them in a string and display, I'm getting in the correct format. If i try to put the entire string in NSURL, it displays NULL.
What is the format to get it?

```
  NSString *booking=urlForBooking.bookHall;
  NSLog(@" book %@",booking);   // this prints ---    http://10.2.0.76:8080/ConferenceHall/BookingHallServlet

  NSString *bookingString=[booking stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?       employeeId=%@&conferenceHallId=%@&bookingId=%d&purpouse=%@&fromDate=%@&toDate=%@&comments=%@&submit=1",empId,_hallId,_bookingId,_purpose,fromDateStr,toDateStr,_comments]];
  NSLog(@"book str %@",bookingString);  //this prints ---   ?employeeId=3306&conferenceHallId=112&bookingId=0&purpouse=S&fromDate=25/Feb/2013 13:29&toDate=25/Feb/2013 15:29&comments=C&submit=1

  NSURL *bookingURL=[NSURL URLWithString:bookingString];
  NSLog(@"BOOK %@",bookingURL);  //here I'm not getting the url(combined string), it gives null.
```

Comment: Your NSLog() output is not consistent with the code. If `bookingString` is made from `booking` by *appending* something, then `bookingString` should start with `"http://10.2.0.76:...."`. Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 3):

That is because the URL your are building contains charters that are not valid in an URL, like spaces and slashes.

You should escape these characters:

```
NSString *bookingPath =[bookingString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *bookingURL=[NSURL URLWithString:bookingPath];
```

You might need to replace the slashes in the date because they might not be encoded correctly.

```
NSString *bookingString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?employeeId=%@&conferenceHallId=%@&bookingId=%d&purpouse=%@&fromDate=%@&toDate=%@&comments=%@&submit=1",
          booking,
          empId,
          _hallId,
          _bookingId,
          [_purpose stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
          [fromDateStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
          [toDateStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
          [_comments stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *bookingURL=[NSURL URLWithString:bookingString];
NSLog(@"BOOK %@",bookingURL);
```

Comment: The you should escape every query paramter on it's own, since your URL still contains illegal characters.

Comment: [empId    stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
          [_hallId stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
          [_bookingId stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],                          Here empId, _hallId, _bookingID are NSNumbers..... I am getting the following warning: 'NSNumber' may not respond to stringByReplacing....And error as: [_NSCFNumber stringByReplacingPercentEscapeUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector  sent to instance.

Comment: You should really be able to fix these kind of error's your self.

Comment: After giving bookingString as i had mentioned, I just gave one line NSURL *bookingUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[bookingString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; I got it in the right format!

Comment: I've changed my code, but you as a developer should be able to solve error as mentioned your self. The `empId`, `_hallId` and `_bookingId` a probably `NSNumber` objects this the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` does not work, something you could have find out your self.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24314/discussion-between-user1999892-and-rckoenes)

Comment: `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is for *de-escaping*, not escaping. You want `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. (And it would probably be more correct to escape the individual query parameters, not the whole URL.

Comment: @PeterHosey I must have been sleeping, thank you for pointing out out that I had the incorrect method. Edit my answer with the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL string is incorrect in some way, and as such is getting parsed to nil. The documentation for [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) tells you this can happen:

> Return Value An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string
>   was malformed, returns nil.

You shouldn't have all those leading spaces after the `?` portion of your URL, and the entire thing needs to be escaped prior to parsing it into a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in _ bookingString_ (before employeeId and in the date) kill your URL.